# number of such numbers

Tags: combinatorics

the number $$916238457$$ is an example of a nine-digit number which contains each of the digit **1** to **9** exactly once. it also has the property that the digits **1** to **5** occur in natural order, while the digits **1** to **6** do not.find the number of such numbers.
i have no idea how to go about it!! someone please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are $9 \choose 6$ different ways to choose the spots of the digits $1$-$6$. Once you choose their spots, the $6$ can go in $5$ different places (all but the last, where it would be in proper order), and the $1$-$5$ have their places determined. The remaining three slots give $3!$ permutations of the $7$-$9$.

This gives a total of ${9 \choose 6}\cdot 5 \cdot 3! = 2520$ numbers fitting your conditions.

Comment: i dont get that
digits 1 to 5 occur in natural order, while the digits 1 to 6 do not
what is it trying to say

Comment: Cross off the digits $6$,$7$,$8$, and $9$ and what remains are the digits $1$ through $5$ in order. That the digits $1$ through $6$ do not occur in order effectively says that the $6$ occurs to the left of the $5$.

Answer (score 6):

*Another way:*

Consider $12345$ in order, then **successively** place $6, 7,8,9\;$ in $\;5*7*8*9 = 2520$ ways

[Always one more than the numbers already placed, except, of course, for $6$ ]

Comment: Can you please exaggerate

Comment: There are always $(n+1)$ unrestricted ways to add a new number to any string of numbers, eg $4$ ways to add to a string of $3$ numbers at the uparrows,  viz $\uparrow 1 \uparrow 2 \uparrow 3\uparrow $. But for this question, $6$ can't appear just after $5$, so only $5$ options for it. For the others, the $(n+1)$ rule will apply on successive placement

Comment: Thank you ! It was really a nice method .